# Change style properties of a html embedded object

Tags: javascript, object, styling

I'm trying to change the padding of an object that I'm inserting with .html:

```
$('#notification-container').html($("<div id = 'notification-count'><span id = 'not-count'>"+ count +"</span></div>"));
$('#notification-count').style.padding = 1px 4px;
```

I'm guessing that doesn't work due to it seeing the element `#notification-count` as not existing. If possible, what would be the best way of accomplishing this? Is there some 'master array' with all the .html embeddings stored or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the second line as

```
$('#notification-count').css('padding', '1px 4px');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery .css() method

```
$(function() {
var count = 25; //default value for try
$('#notification-container').html('<div id="notification-count"><span id="not-count">'+ count +'</span></div>');
$('#notification-count').css({'padding':'1px 4px'});
});
```